# How to print 3 strings in same line ?

Tags: racket

I have a list of strings in `kumo`. I am printing three strings. I am getting them on 3 lines. I want them on one line separated by spaces. I am using the following code:

```
(display (first kumo))

(display (fourth kumo)) 

(display (second kumo))
```

or

```
(printf "~a~a~a" (first kumo)(fourth kumo)(second kumo))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm... unless I'm misunderstanding you, Racket already does that.  Here's a small (complete) program illustrating this:

```
#lang racket

(define kumo (list "the" "very" "big" "dog"))

(printf "~a~a~a" (first kumo)(fourth kumo)(second kumo))
```

... which produces

```
thedogvery
```

If you want spaces between the words, put them in the format string:

```
#lang racket

(define kumo (list "the" "very" "big" "dog"))

(printf "~a ~a ~a" (first kumo)(fourth kumo)(second kumo))
```

... which produces

```
the dog very
```

You can do the same thing with `display`, by displaying a string containing a single space in between the calls that display the words.

If I had to guess at your problem, I'd say that the strings you're displaying have newlines embedded in them.